# R GIS intersecting lines and polygons (large data)

Tags: r, vector, gis, polygon, polyline

GIS and R question:

I need to intersect many **lines** with many **polygons**.

Ideally I would like to do this in R.

Where one line crosses a polygon boundary, I would like that line to be split (making two features / lines).

I would then like to attribute the new (often smaller) lines with the attributes of the polygon that they are now within.

If the lines lie outside a polygon, I would expect the new attributes attached from the polygon to the lines would be NULL or NA or empty.

I am happy to load the data as either **shapefiles** or **geopackages**.

What is the best tool to do this with in R?

(I'm happy to use packages such as **Raster**, **rgeos** and **SF** etc. However, ideally, if we can avoid calling QGIS or other software unless it is very stable that would be great. I don't have a licence for Arc)

Many thanks indeed.

Comment: You already have the answer - use the `sf` package and its various geometry functions. Make a small data set with maybe ten different features and work out how to do it. If you still can't, then give us access to that data set and show us your work so far.

Comment: OK, thanks, I'll give that a try. I hope it is faster than QGIS which is taking hours (days even) to process.

Answer (score 1):

Let's collect some online data, a polygon and a couple of lines. We will use `osmdata` to fetch `OSM` data for my village.

```r
library(osmdata)
#> Data (c) OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.8.0, GDAL 3.0.4, PROJ 6.3.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
library(tidyverse)
```

Let's find a bounding box and add a bit of space to it

```
Lbb <- getbb("Lubnów trzebnicki Poland")
addM <- matrix(data = c(-0.01, -0.01, 0.01, 0.01), nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
newBB <- Lbb + addM
```

Let's fetch highways (lines, multilines) and boundaries (polygons, multipolygons) which we will use in our calculations

```
highways <- opq (newBB) |> 
  add_osm_feature (key = "highway") |>
  osmdata_sf()

highways <- highways$osm_lines |>
  select(osm_id, name, geometry) |>
  st_as_sf()

boundaries <- opq(newBB) |>
  add_osm_feature (key = "boundary", value = "administrative") |>
  osmdata_sf()

boundariesWsi <- boundaries$osm_multipolygons |>
  filter(boundary == "administrative" & admin_level == 8 & name == "Lubnów")
```

And let's plot it for visualization

```
plot(boundariesWsi$geometry, col = "gray90")
plot(highways$geometry, lwd = 0.6, lty = 4, add = TRUE)
```

[image]

We will create a supporting `MULTILINESTRING` corresponding to village boundaries, which we will use to find only those ways, which croses the boundary

```
boundariesWsiAsLines <- st_cast(boundariesWsi, "MULTILINESTRING")
```

Now, let's find those `interestingHighways` which crosses the village boundaries:

```
interestingHighways <- highways |> 
  filter(st_intersects(boundariesWsiAsLines$geometry, highways$geometry, sparse = FALSE))
```

and finally, find IN and OUT parts of those highways:

```
a<- st_as_sf(st_intersection(interestingHighways$geometry, boundariesWsi$geometry))
b<- st_as_sf(st_difference(interestingHighways$geometry, boundariesWsi$geometry))

plot(a, lwd = 4, col = "darkblue", add = TRUE)
plot(b, lwd = 4, col = "darkgreen", add = TRUE)
```

[image]

Instead of one multipolygon, you can have a list of multipolygons. To assign the attributes to ways, you can use `dplyr::mutate()`.

<sup>Created on 2022-01-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>